# How do you consider the negative states i.e. ...-3,-2,-1, when solving for the stationary distribution of this MC?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, stochastic-processes, markov-process

[image]

I have shown that the MC is aperiodic and irreducible, if that helps.

Comment: It's unclear why having negative numbers among the states would be a problem. What method do you have in mind for finding the stationary distribution?

Comment: The challenge I am having is how to set up the transition matrix. As it is symmetrical, can I only consider the positive direction states?

Comment: That would work, but needs careful justification.  The transition matrix is "doubly bi-infinite," but it's still manageable, particularly because it's sparse.  Have you tried writing the equations that characterize a stationary distribution?